# Transposing a big table, zip limitations

Tags: python, zip, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a table using this code:

```
def transpose_otu_table(otu_table):
    with open(otu_table) as f:
        rows = [x.split() for x in f]
    transposed_rows = zip(*rows)
    with open(otu_table.rstrip('.txt') + '_TRANS.txt', 'a') as newfile:
        for new_row in transposed_rows:
            towrit = ''
            for el in new_row:
                towrit += el + '\t'
            towrit.rstrip('\t')
            towrit += '\n'
            newfile.write(towrit)
    return()
```

It works perfectly for small tables, but when I try it with real data it creates an empty file.

I suppose it has something to do with memory limitations on zip.

How can I overcome this problem?

[Data example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvv19ly1a6u93p0/cont_file.txt?dl=0)

Comment: your indentation is broken, which makes your code ambiguous. You **must** fix this. **Otherwise no-one can reliably help you**

Comment: `zip` doesn't have (nearly) any memory limitations. It just gives you a generator. `*rows` might have interesting effects, but that should just give you a generator, too.

Comment: If you aren't already familiar with `pandas`, you may want to take a look and see if that provides an easier solution for you: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html